# Characterization of a finitely graded (almost) domain

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, graded-rings-modules

Let $A= \bigoplus_{i=0}^{N}A_i$ be a finitely graded ring with the following property:  if $x \in A_i$ and $y \in A_j$ and $i+j \leq N$, then
$$xy = 0 \text{ implies } x = 0 \text{ or } y = 0.$$
Hence this ring is "almost" an integral domain until degree $N+1$.

Do these types of rings have a name?

If we assume $A$ is noetherian then it must be a finitely generated algebra over the noetherian ring $A_0$ and thus the quotient $R/I$ of a polynomial ring $R$ over $A_0$.

Are there any necessary and sufficient conditions we may impose on $I$ so that the property above holds?

Comment: To be clear, are you asking that $ab\neq 0$ when $a,b\neq 0$ or that $ab\neq 0$ when $a\otimes b\neq 0$?  It might be the case that $a\otimes b=0$ in $A_i\otimes_{A_0}A_j$ even if $a$ and $b$ are both nonzero.

Comment: The first sentence is indeed unclear (whenever... iff ... sounds weird)

Comment: @EricWofsey It should be $ab \neq 0$ when $a,b \neq 0$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I edited to drop the tensor, does this make more sense?

Comment: @YCor Clearly $ab=0$ when $i+j >N$ or $a=b=0$ since $A_N$ is the last nonzero group in the direct sum. The other direction is the condition I'm more interested in

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the opening for clarity and conciseness (since I know the person who posed the question).