# Can a ideal-like subset that is prime in low degrees be extended to a prime ideal ?

Tags: graded-rings-modules

Let $A=\bigoplus_{n \ge 0}A_n$ be a positively graded commutative ring. Let $J_n \le A_n$ be subgroups for $j=0,\ldots,N$, satisfying

1. $\,\,\,A_n \cdot J_m \subseteq J_{n+m}$ for $n+m \le N$
2. $\,\,\,x \cdot y \in J \Rightarrow  x \in J$ or $y \in J$  for all homogeneous $x,y \in A$ with $\deg(xy)\le N$

where $J = \bigoplus_{n=0}^NJ_n$.

These two conditions just say that $J$ behaves like a prime ideal in degrees where the products are defined.

**Question:** Can $J$ be extended to a homogeneous prime ideal, i.e. is there a homogeneous prime ideal $P \subseteq A$ such that $P_n = J_n$ for $n=0,\ldots,N$ ?

**Motivation:** The question came up to me than I was thinking about this question: [Characterization of a finitely graded (almost) domain](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256064/characterization-of-a-finitely-graded-almost-domain): If the question above has an affirmative answer and if I'm not mistaken, then the ideals in the linked question are exactly of the form $I= P + R_{> N}$ for a prime ideal $P$. But I think, the question above is interesting in its own right to ask it as a separate question.

Comment: It is false in general if you do not assume $1 \notin J_0$.

Comment: Let's assume $1 \not\in J_0$ as additional condition.